# Is there any limit to the implements and extends in the activities?

Tags: android, class, extends, implements

I am getting error from the following sentence

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment, AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener  {
```

I am not aware of any limit, what could be wrong?

Comment: You can implement any number of interfaces but you can only extend one class.

Comment: therefore, how can I implement Fragment and Activity at the same time?

Comment: @MDR Simple: You **can't**.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class, you are basically saying "Start with Fragment, then apply my extension functionality over the top." Hence you cannot extend two distinct classes.

When you implement an interface, it is like saying "Add these connections to my class." So you can implement multiple interfaces in one class.

Comment: aka the second class should be extended in the parent activity in the case of a Navigation Drawer, right?

Comment: Yes, your app's activity should extend `AppCompatActivity`, any custom fragments you're writing should extend `Fragment` (or `FragmentCompat`), etc. Each class can have exactly zero or one parents (super classes).